# Mysql random within set order

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the top 4 records ordered by a specific column descending. If more than one value is the same then I need to randomise them.

For example:

```
ID -  VALUE
1  -  10
2  -  5
3  -  5
4  -  3
5  -  3
6  -  3
7  -  3
8  -  3
9  -  3
10 -  3
```

So in this example 10 is the highest so will always be top. 5 is the second highest so it will randomly order both of the 5 values. it will then select a random one with the value of 3.

I hope this is clear.

edit:
I have tried ORDER BY Value DESC and assumed that it would select them randomly but it seems as though there is a predetermined order as the same ones keep displaying.

I have also tried ORDER BY Value DESC, RAND(ID) which does the same as above but with different values.

Comment: And now all you need to do, is to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Can you explain properly what you want ? and what you have tried before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this ORDER clause:

```
SELECT ... ORDER BY your_column DESC, RAND()
```

Comment: Beautiful. This works exactly as I wanted. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yep, I am just waiting for a stackoverflow delay that they have put in before I can mark it as solved.